# Angular 6 - Show s3 file upload download progress in Angular MatDialog

Tags: angular, material-design

I want to pass progress percentage data from calling component to MatDialog. Using dialogref or by Injecting data in Dialog component constructor I'm only able to set the variable with an initial value. But the value is not updated as it's updated inside the calling component.

The idea is to have a progress bar with percentage in a dialog to block user action during upload/download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `shared service` or just create `service` to your module from which you are launching dialog, in service create `Observable` and `Subject` of current progress, modal should listen to `Observable` and on `Subject` just use `.next(progressValue)` to update value.

You can learn more [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service), it's about parent and children, but if dialog is in the same module as component/service there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 1):

use httpdownloadprogress in getObject function you can check the progress of download

```
.on('httpDownloadProgress',(progress) => {     
                 // shows file download progress
        });
```

Here is the entire code including download function

```
import { config, SecretsManager, S3 , CognitoIdentityCredentials} from 'aws-sdk';

    const bucket = new S3({
                        accessKeyId: <accessKeyId>,
                        secretAccessKey: <secretAccessKey>,
                        region: <region>
                    });

    const params = {        
                      Bucket: <BucketName>,
                      Key: <fileName>,
                   };

       bucket.getObject(params, (err:any, data:any) =>{
            if (err) {
                 // shows AWS s3 error
             }else{
                 // response of binary data 

             }
        }).on('httpDownloadProgress',(progress) => {     
                 // shows file download progress
        });
```